# Example of random variable $X > 0$ with finite expectation but infinite $E[X \log_+(X)]$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, expected-value

I am looking for an example of a random variable $X > 0$ with finite expectation but infinite $E[X \log_+(X)]$.

I considered the [heavy tail distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution) that I know. But none of them seems to satisfy this condition.

This is equivalent of finding an example of density function $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ such that
$$
\int_{0}^\infty f(x) \mathbb d x = 1;
$$
$$
\int_{0}^\infty x f(x) \mathbb d x < \infty;
$$
but
$$
\int_{1}^\infty x \log(x) f(x) \mathbb d x = \infty.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take for example 
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
c\frac 1{x^2(\log x)^2}&\mbox{ for }x>e; \\
0&\mbox{ for }x\leqslant e,
\end{cases}
$$
where $c$ is such that $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x)dx=1$.